# ember.js and jQuery-UI multiselect widget

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js

I need an advanced multiselect element (with search function) for my ember application.

I like [this](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) jQuery-UI Multiselect widget and started with this code:

```
// app.js
...
App.MultiSelectView = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    console.log("Creating multiSelect element");
    $("#mselect").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
  },
});
App.multiSelectView = App.MultiSelectView.create();
...

// index.html
...
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="mulselect">
  <select id="mselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  {{view App.multiSelectView}}
</script>
...
```

This code works and displays the widget. But I don't know how to bind the values/names to an ember controller/object.

[This](http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/) blog post seems to point into right direction, but as I said, I haven't found a solution yet because I'm new to ember (and javascript).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to ember and javascript I would strongly advise against trying to integrate JQUI and ember. JQUI components tend to make a lot of assumptions about what the HTML looks like - any framework that adds tags in unexpected places is going to break most JQUI components. Likewise ember's data-binding feature cannot work on a part of the DOM that is being rendered by a 3rd party library.

That said, I gave it a shot. You can get pretty close by using unbound helper like so:

```
<select id="mselect" multiple="multiple">
  {{each option in controller}}
    <option>{{unbound option.txt}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

I've posted a partial solution here: http://jsbin.com/uxarij/13/edit

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Not marked as accepted, because I need the filter. But I think you are right, I will look for a simpler solution (a combination of ember.select's) and avoid jQuery-UI widgets. It's to hard to understand for a newbie :)

Comment: @Michael I have been using Ember+JQuery UI for a few months now. In our application I have implemented *sortable*, *draggable*, *droppable*, and *accordion* widgets successfully and I have not run into any binding issues. JQUI functionality fit well into mixins and since we can create elements inside template first, bindings are safe. If ember didnt work with other libraries that work with dom elements, then that would be a huge downside. Luckily that is not the case.

Comment: @Aras totally agreed, it's possible to use ember with other libraries like JQUI, would be a huge downside if you couldn't. FWIW we are using Ember+JQueryUI as well so not trying to say it can't/shouldn't be done. In my experience some of the jqui components are more challenging to integrate than others. As i remember JQUI Autocomplete was a bit tricky, and this filter plugin seems to have the same kind of challenges. Just cause I couldn't make it work in < 5 minutes doesn't mean it can't be done. Since the poster is new to both ember and javascript I'm recommending they avoid if possible.